# How to use Erlang conditionals (RabbitMQ and Erlang)

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I am trying to figure out how to create some more granular authentication/authorization in `rabbitmq.config`.  I think the language it uses is referred to as Erlang (is that right?).

I tried the following in an attempt to use the conditionals, but it failed:

```
{vhost_access_query,
  {in_group,
    {'or', [
      "CN=${vhost}-users,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com",
      "CN=${vhost}-admins,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com",
      "CN=${vhost}-consumers,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com",
      "CN=${vhost}-producers,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com"
    ]}
}},
```

Anyway, it does not like it.  What I was trying to do was say vhost access is allowed for any of the four groups-in that, `group1`, or `group2`, or `group3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Aside: RabbitMQ is written in Erlang. The configuration file uses Erlang-style terms (`{a, tuple}`, `["a", list]`), but it's* not *Erlang.*

Looking at the RabbitMQ [documentation for the LDAP plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ldap.html), it says that `'or'` takes a list of sub-**queries**:

```
{'or', [SubQuery1, SubQuery2, SubQuery3, ...]}
```

This implies that what you actually need is something like this:

```
{vhost_access_query,
    {'or',
        [
         {in_group, "CN=${vhost}-users,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com"},
         {in_group, "CN=${vhost}-admins,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com"},
         {in_group, "CN=${vhost}-consumers,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com"},
         {in_group, "CN=${vhost}-producers,ou=vhosts,ou=MIS,ou=ISD,ou=US,ou=Servers,dc=domain,dc=com"}
        ]
    }
},
```

...but don't quote me on that (unless I'm right); I've never used the LDAP plugin.

Comment: That seems to work for that part as quoted by Roger Libscombe.